# Could this be possible? <img src="LINK WITHOUT IMAGE FORMAT" />

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, format

¿Is there a way to insert into html image element a link without the image format and watch and specific image of that link? And what happend if that link has only the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No it is not directly supported.

You could Call a Service, who make a Picture of this site (or make your own) and provide a Link to this Picture.

For example:

http://www.convertapi.com/web-image-api

Or Take a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6678156/2441442

Comment: mmm, I think I did not explain well.
If i insert URLDOMAIN/jhdfjd. Then there are lot of images in it, but there is one that has a JS code for example, and if you insert the URL (not the image URL) on src="" attribute, then that image appear.